# Store a field on a node

Tags: 8, forms, files

I altered the node form and added an `manage_file`-field; then, I added a callback on the `#entity_builders` property.

```
$fid = $form_state->getValue('file')[0];
$file = File::load($fid);

$file->setPermanent();
$file->save();

// $node->set('field_file', $file);
$node->field_file->setValue([
  'target_id' => $file->id(),
]);
```

However this gives me the following error:

> The file used in the File field may not be referenced.

At this point, I cannot use file_usage, since the node is not yet saved.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Why you use Form API `manage_file`? Add the field to the entity or content type. If you already done this, use a form mode to add the field to a node form.

Comment: You get an error like that if you have a non-allowed file extension, file size or similar validation error. But yes, I also don't understand what you're doing here and why you don't use the standard widget.

Answer (score 0):

Set the status of the created file to something other than PERMANENT.

So replace

```
$file->setPermanent();
```

with

```
$file->status = 0;
```

The file field will then set the status to `permanent` and add the file_usage metadata.